# set a window to open once only unless needed

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

i am designing a password encryption application, and want to password protect a database that is created when the software is first started, with a password the user chooses.

So how do i set the application to run a certain part only once in its lifetime? And how do i assign a textbox value to the SQL Compact edition databases password?

P.S I will be using SHA256 for the encryption with random salts and hashing, in case anyone wants to tell me a better way?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, How to execute once. mark some field as flag in your database or create a new table with the flags and check for its value on `Form_Load` if the flag is found, open some other default form, such as dashboard etc.

for the second part, get the full understanding and attack your problem, from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.compact(VS.80).aspx

```
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = db.sdf");
engine.Compact(null);
engine.Compact("Data Source=; Password =pass;");
```

By flag, I mean any field that you would populate on the first time.
For example in my web app, I have used the super admin record as flag. I query the table of super admin to find if there is any record. if there is a record. I would not allow to open the page for creating super admin page.
If there is no such data in your app. create a table with one column, and when you have set the password once, insert the value in this table. and when ever the form is requested, check this table for any records.(Alternately inset value 0 in the column of type tinyint and make it one when you set the password )

Comment: could you elaborate on the 'flag'? how would i do that? My thoughts were just to check if the database existed, if it did, open another form instead?

Comment: By flag, I mean any field that you would populate on the first time.
either a used field in your application or a special field in a special table created to serve this purpose. read details above.